# Creating an NPM package that enables ES6 imports to cherry pick exports

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, rollupjs

When building an NPM package, how do you create a build that is able to support *cherry picking* individual exports to save on Webpack, Rollup or Browserify bundle size?

Preferred syntax would be:

`import { myModuleOne, myModuleTwo } from 'my-npm-package';`

Or

```
import myModuleOne from 'my-npm-package/myModuleOne';
import myModuleTwo from 'my-npm-package/myModuleTwo';
```

Comment: Use [`require`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) as Node.js does not support ES6 modules, yet.

Comment: @str But webpack and Rollup do.

Comment: @Gothdo Sure, when developing. But you should not (cannot?) publish an NPM package with ES6 modules as not all package users might use either of webpack or Rollup.

Comment: @str You can create an UMD bundle and set it as `main` in `package.json`, and an ES module bundle and set it as `module` in `package.json`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use ES6 exports:

```
export const myModuleOne = ...
export const myModuleTwo = ...
```

And in `package.json` set the `module` property to the path of your bundle:

```
{
  main: 'path/to/umd/bundle.js',
  module: 'path/to/es/bundle.js',
  ...
}
```

Rollup and webpack 2 have tree-shaking, so the generated bundle will include only the modules you need.

Comment: will you please explain in more details.